# Lock web service method for one client

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, thread-safety

This is my scenario: I'm working on an e-commerce system (ASP.NET MVC) which users can 'Like' products. I have a method in my web service (.svc) which if the user has already liked that product, it removes the like, and if the user has not, it adds a like for product.

I have an issue here: I call the 'Like' method via Ajax asynchronously, if the user clicks on the like button multiple times continuously, so, the method is called multiple times continuously. since this method is not thread-safe, I might have issues here. (For example, it might insert the like multiple times for one single user in the database)

I've been trying to make it Thread-safe by using `lock` statement, but apparently, It still doesn't work.
This is my web service method:

```
    private static Object productLikeLock = new Object();
    [WebMethod, ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public bool ToggleProductLike(int productId)
    {
        try
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                lock (productLikeLock)
                {

                    if (/* User has already liked the product */)
                    {
                        // Remove it from the database
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Add it to the database
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me and let me know what is wrong with my code and approach?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a question, if you're using MVC, why are you also using the ancient asmx style webservices instead of using a Web API, which is the modern recommended way and generally easier to work with? It's not related to your issue, just a strange design decision.

Comment: @ADyson I use WCF, It was a writing mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really want is the lock to only be active for the user, not for the whole application. A private static is not a good fit for the lock here. You could potentially use a `Dictionary<UserId, LockObject>` for the lock, but this is still not great.

What I would suggest is not trying to implement this function as a toggle. Toggling state will always get you into this sort of trouble.

Try re-engineering the application to have an explicit `Like` and `Dislike` action. That way you don't have to lock anything.

Comment: That's right. But I think I would have still had this problem even if I split the 'Toggle' method into two separated methods. because when the client sends multiple requests to 'Like' method, we would have had this story again.

Comment: The `like` method should be idempotent for repeat calls, it will set the value to 'liked' for that product and that user. Ensure that the state for this is only represented in your data model once, don't record each `like` call separately.

Comment: Could you please provide a very very simple example of how to create a db model based on what you said (storing 'Liked' status instead of storing user like in each row). Because I can't even make it in my mind. It's very important to me. Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have a `Likes` table/object that represents the link, it contains a foreign key to a User and a Product, and nothing else (maybe a PK). Either create link row (like) or delete like row (unlike). These actions are then easily repeatable.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, but this way we have this problem again. :)